# Iterate through javascript nested objects

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I have following json object :

"records": {
        "abc": {
            "id": "1",
            "code": "A",
            "iId": "2",
        },
        "xyz": {
            "id": "1",
            "code": "B",
            "iId": "2", 
        }
    }

I want to get code values and insert them into a new array. How can I achieve it ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's try code below:

```js
let obj = {
  "records": { 
    "abc": { 
      "id": "1", 
      "code": "A", 
      "iId": "2", 
    }, 
    "xyz": { 
      "id": "1", 
      "code": "B", 
      "iId": "2", 
    } 
  }
};

let arr = [];

for (let key in obj) {
    for (let subkey in obj[key]){
      arr.push(obj[key][subkey]['code']);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```